# I want to get a "feature" by setting the area based on the point where I click. with bbox

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms

I want to get a "feature" by setting the area based on the point where I click.

I tried putting bbox in "source" but it failed.

```
   var coordinate = map.getEventCoordinate(evt);

   var bboxString = (coordinate[1] - 1) + "," +
   (coordinate[0] - 1) + "," +
   (coordinate[1] + 1) + "," +
   (coordinate[0] + 1);

   var untiled = new ol.layer.Image({
       source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
         ratio: 1,
         url: '.../wms',
         params: {'FORMAT': 'image/png',
                  'VERSION': '1.3',  
               "LAYERS": layerWmsString,
               "CRS" : map.getView().getProjection(),
               "BBOX" : bboxString,                 
               "exceptions": 'application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage'
         },
         projection : map.getView().getProjection(),
         serverType : 'geoserver'
       })   
     });

   var url = untiled.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
           coordinate, viewResolution, view.getProjection(),
     {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json', 'FEATURE_COUNT': 50});
```

bbox is not working.

Comment: It is intended for layers displayed on a map and OpenLayers will automatically set the bbox, width and height to match the view https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.source.ImageWMS.html **params: WIDTH, HEIGHT, BBOX and CRS (SRS for WMS version < 1.3.0) will be set dynamically.** If you want a GetFeatureInfo request on a layer not displayed on the map it might be simpler to construct the url yourself.  Give width and height an arbitrary value and set i and j to half of that.

Comment: thanks, but i don't understand i,j what is mean

Comment: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo

Comment: i and j are pixel coordinates in the map image that you are querying

Comment: According to the WMS specification version must be `1.3.0` or `1.1.1`... but not just `1.3`